# How to prove this using laws?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

How do they prove this?

$$(p\to q)\land[\neg q\land(r\lor\neg q)]\equiv\neg q\land\neg p$$

Comment: Did you make a typo with that weird equals sign? I think that isnt proper notation...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No, it’s fine; it stands for logical equivalence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  thank you so much for the edit. Im just using phone so its hard for me to use other sign. Only ^ and v

Comment: @CamsB: You’re welcome. If you use MathJax (for which there’s a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you can get everything that I wrote there without needing any unusual special symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: One of the absorption laws tells you that $\neg q\land(r\lor\neg q)\equiv\neg q$, so the lefthand side is equivalent to

$$(p\to q)\land\neg q\;.$$

Now use the fact that $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$, apply a distributive law, and do a little simplifying.

Comment: (-p v q) ^ -q then do de morgan law? Im going to distribute -q to -p and q?

Comment: @CamsB: Yes, my fingers got ahead of my brain there. It’s fixed now; thanks!

Comment: I end up with (-q ^ -p) v (-q ^q) then i used complement law and end up with (-q ^ -p) v F. How can i cancel F? What law is that?

Comment: @CamsB: I don’t know exactly what set of laws you’re using; in my experience $p\lor\text{F}\equiv p$ is often taken as one of the laws.

Comment: Oh. But if the P is negate, is the answer still -p? Like (-p v F) = -p ?

Comment: @CamsB: Absolutely: $p$ can be any proposition, no matter how complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it now. I thought its forbidden.

Comment: @CamsB: You’re very welcome. The same goes for all of the other laws, by the way: in the distributive law $$x\land(y\lor z)\equiv(x\land y)\lor(x\land z)$$ the $x,y$, and $z$ can themselves be compound propositions.